# Print a string in a loop php

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a table in which i should put some values inside the `<td></td>`.

What I have is a `$checked` value which I convert it in some string like: `id1,id2,id3`

What I need to do is a loop which permits me to print this values like this.  Something like this:

```
(for i=0, i<length of words, i++) {
echo "<td> .id[i].</td>"
}
```

My real variable is this:

```
 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    echo "<pre>";
    $checked = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']);
    echo $checked;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

If `$_POST['checkbox']` is already an array then you don't have to `implode()` it before processing :

```
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $id) {
    echo '<td>' . $id . '</td>';
}
```

Comment: Yes, in fact it was stupid from my part to post this question, i already found a solution :) thanks!

Comment: Note that this will fail and issue a warning if `$_POST['checkbox']` is not an array (very possible).

Comment: One question please, i see better now, i need to print only the checkbox values, but how can i limit it to print me just 4 values, i mean if the checkbox is an array and has 4 values, it should print me 4..